# Should I delete my comments once the OP has acted accordingly?

Tags: support, comments

The title is a bit vague. Let me explain.

Now, just yesterday, I posted a comment like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/520398/how-can-one-e-field-formula-be-rewritten-to-another-version#comment1174273_520398) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/520379/commutator-of-annihilation-operator-and-momentum-operator#comment1174243_520379). In these comments, I requested the OP to use Mathjax and to avoid using images. Now, both the questions have been edited (one by the OP and the other by someone else). So, should I delete my comments now, because they no longer make any sense?

---

<sup>The comments were deleted, so the links are dead.</sup>

Comment: I have deleted some obsolete comments. Your amusement is optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes... I have nothing further to say.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Jim's very detailed answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12595/179151), I will add that you can only delete your own comments. If there were also comments by other users that have become obsolete you should additionally flag these comments as "no longer needed" to be removed by mods. That way there aren't unneeded, irrelevant comments hanging around.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of doing that. But, now I will also flag those other ones.

Comment: FWIW if you flag two or three comments on the same post, we'll usually get the message and consider deleting all of them. Another option is to flag the post itself with a custom flag asking for comments to be removed - that's _marginally_ less convenient for us, but just as effective.